# Double free in C implementation of Queue

Tags: c, queue, free, double-free

Here is my implementation of a Queue class in c, the struct queue_object* contains a void* object and a queue_object* next.
Adding char 'A' and 'B' seems to work out, polling once too, but at the second poll I get:

free(): double free detected in tchache 2

I really dont get why I should be freeing one adress twice, please help!!

```
int queue_add(void* new_object, queue_object* queue) {
    if (new_object == NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else if (queue == NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else if (queue->object == NULL) {
        queue->object = new_object;
        return 0;
    }

    queue_object* newelement = (queue_object*) malloc(sizeof(queue_object));
    if (newelement == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    newelement->object = new_object;
    newelement->next = NULL;

    queue_object* tmp = queue;
    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    tmp->next = newelement;
    return 0;
}


void* queue_poll(queue_object* queue) {
    if (queue == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (queue != NULL && queue->next == NULL) {
        void* data = queue->object;
        free(queue);
        return data;
    }
    void* data = queue->object;
    queue_object* tmp = queue;
    queue = queue->next;
    free(tmp);  // Entferne die Speicherfreigabe für tmp
    return data;
}

queue_object* new_queue(){
    // TODO
    queue_object* q = (queue_object*) malloc(sizeof(queue_object));
    if (q==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    q->next = NULL;
    q->object = NULL;
    return q;
}


void free_queue(queue_object* queue){
    // TODO
    if(queue == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        queue_object* tmp0 = NULL;
        while (queue != NULL){
            tmp0 = queue;
            queue = queue->next;
            free(tmp0);
        }
    }
}

void* queue_peek(queue_object* queue){
    // TODO
    if(queue == NULL || queue->object == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    return queue->object;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what line has the fault? It's likely a use-after-free bug.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: That line in `queue_poll` is void: `queue = queue->next;` And I suspect it has something to do with your error, since you seem to expect that this line effect would be to shift the queue to skip the 1st element (that you've freed). But `queue` remains unchanged. Execpt that its first element is now a freed pointer. So next time you trill to poll or free it...

Comment: why should queue remain the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. We need the minimal code and data necessary so we can run and duplicate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

no to going into details there are quick minimal fixes in queue_add(), queue_poll(), free_queue()
note: call them properly, for example `queue_poll(&queue)`

queue_add

```
-int queue_add(void* new_object, queue_object* queue) {
+int queue_add(void* new_object, queue_object** q) {
+    queue_object* queue = *q;
     if (new_object == NULL) {
         return 1;
     } else if (queue == NULL) {
```

queue_poll

```
-void* queue_poll(queue_object* queue) {
+void* queue_poll(queue_object** q) {
+    queue_object* queue = *q;
     if (queue == NULL) {
         return NULL;
     }
     if (queue != NULL && queue->next == NULL) {
         void* data = queue->object;
         free(queue);
+         *q = NULL;
         return data;
     }
     void* data = queue->object;
-    queue_object* tmp = queue;
-    queue = queue->next;
-    free(tmp);  // Entferne die Speicherfreigabe für tmp
+    *q = queue->next;
+    free(queue);  // Entferne die Speicherfreigabe für tmp
     return data;
 }
```

free_queue

```
-void free_queue(queue_object* queue){
+void free_queue(queue_object** q){
+    queue_object* queue = *q;
     // TODO
     if(queue == NULL){
         return;
     }
     else{
-        queue_object* tmp0 = NULL;
         while (queue != NULL){
-            tmp0 = queue;
-            queue = queue->next;
-            free(tmp0);
+            *q = queue->next;
+            free(queue);
+            queue = *q;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer but "no to going into details" weakens it considerably in my opinion. Helping someone understand why this code works better is important.

Comment: supposed it follows from @chrslg above comment on changing viariables inside of the function scope, so it's just addition how to fix them (plus a couple others)

Comment: I get your solution, but sadly I cannot change the header of the function, can you explain what might be wrong with my code? I really dont get it...

Comment: @chiefsteve arguments of a function are local to its function, consider this:
`
fn(int a) { a = 2; };
main {
int a = 1;
fn(a);
printf("%d\n", a); /* still 1, not 2 */
}
`
the same with fn(queue) { queue = something; }

Comment: Yeah, thats call by value... but since I am giving my function pointers, shouldn't the value of the pointer be overwritten when doing queue = queue->next ?? How would you fix this?

Comment: in scope of that function you have changed the value of local variable named 'queue', it doesn't alter an external variable with the same name 'queue'.
I.e. you operate with _two_ variables named with the same name 'queue'.
<br>
howto fix: a lot of options
- you can return altered value instead of 'int' in queue_poll()
- you can chage 'queue' by using pointer on it, i.e. queue_poll(&queue)
- redesign infrastracture
- etc.

Comment: Due to the task, I cannot change the environment nor the header of the function... Please have a look at the pthread_kill error I get with gdb, could it be that the error is due to my environment? I appriciate your help, thanks

Comment: "pthread_kill error I get with gdb":<br>
it's aborted because "double free"

Comment: "I cannot change the environment nor the header of the function"<br>
you can enlarge that queue on one pseudo "queue_object" in front of the real queue, and keep your pointer on real queue in "->next" field of the first element. But it would be a wrong design with unnecessary complexity, so that I'd not recommend it.

Comment: Yeah I also thought of that, but would be very very ugly. Is there no other option while preserving the headers & so on? This is a task from uni, so there should be a better solution? I dont think they want a pseudo element in their test cases :/

Comment: there's maybe something misread in that task, because you cannot change an external variable by changing its local copy (as it done in your example of code)

Comment: but isn't that also done in the add function (??) - and that is working...

Comment: what's "that"? in the original of 'add' function there's addition of 'newelement' at the tail of queue

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code. Supplying the solution as diff changes weakens its value considerably.